# Polling an API repeatedly with a factory or service in Angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I need to poll an API every 3 seconds with angular 1.3. The method I need to run is:

```
$scope.getCurrentConversation = function(){
CommonServices.getAllConversations($scope.api_key)
  .then(function(_data) {
    $scope.conversations = _data.data;
  });
}
```

The following message is defined in CommonServices.getCurrentConversation. If that looks strange, I do it to consolidate "common services" that are used in more than one controller. It just returns a promise that updates a $scope variable to repopulate the DOM vi an ng-repeat that displays the data.

```
getCurrentConversation: function(api_key, conversation_id){
    return $http({
        url: '/api/v1/conversations/' + conversation_id,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { 'X-API-TOKEN': api_key },
        data: ''
    })
  }
```

These functions work fine but I need to call the first one every 3 seconds and I am unsure as to whether a factory or service would be a better approach than setting up some sort of timer loop in the active controller and firing them as-is. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I realize polling is not an optimal solution and that websockets etc. may be a better way to go, but I haven't experimented with them yet and I am not sure how robust connection would be for mobil clients etc. Any information, links etc about the overall approach would also be appreciated.

Comment: I now it's not the purpose of the question, but requesting a Webservice every 2-3s may not be a viable solution. you may need to rethink your strategy of Data Retrieval Logic.
You may have a look to the SocketIO that permit to initiate a session between the server and the client, and then, on server modification, you can notify the client to trigger a Get.

About the architecture of your files, I think you may have a look on the Pattern: **API Gateway**. it may help you to search within the existing implementations.

And for your question, Service will be better.

Comment: I'd expect you wouldn't want to put the "every 3 seconds" part into a Service or Factory. It feels *implementation* specific (would everything talking to this Service want the same burden of having to deal with new data every 3 seconds?) I'd expect a `$timeout($scope.getCurrentConversation, 3000);` at the end of the controller would suffice. Though others may disagree on this...

Answer (score 0):

The only real advantage you're going to see with a factory is that you can call `new` to create multiple factories.  I don't know if you'd want to have multiple factories each polling every 3 seconds, but if you don't then there is effectively no difference.

You might be better served by using a service, since it's a bit simpler when starting out.

**edit**

I also agree with DRobinson above that a factory/service might not be the best place for a `$interval` since it will stay alive even when you're in another controller, etc., so it will likely be good to place it in the controller as needed.

Comment: for "every 3 seconds", should it use $interval instead of $timeout